# xlrd,xlwt in python (how to copy an entire row)

Tags: python, excel, copy, row, xlwt

Ideally i am copying an entire row from another excel worksheet. So instead of showing that code, my problem starts from when i have that row in a list, how do i put it in another excel worksheet now? I want it to look exactly the same. Goal: Take either of the data formats, and putting them in a blank excel worksheet in e.g. row 1. I would like this to be something fast, since i plan to scale it up to 10,000 rows.

Data can be in either format:

```
data = [number:6842.0, xldate:41771.0, xldate:0.005555555555555556,
        text:u'Hello World']
data = [6842.0, 41771.0, 0.005555555555555556, u'Hello World']
```

My Code:

```
import xlwt
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
data = [6842.0, 41771.0, 0.005555555555555556, u'Hello World'] #either format
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet("MyData")
sheet1.write(1,0,data)
wb.save('C:\\Python27\\helloworld.xls')
```

This is how i am grabbing my data from an excel file:

```
from xlrd import *
import xlwt

book = open_workbook(filename= 'C:\Users\ssheikh\Desktop\CopyFile.xls')
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet("MyData")

b = xldate.xldate_from_date_tuple((2014,5,12), 0) 
c = xldate.xldate_from_date_tuple((2014,5,13), 0)

mylist = []
listc = []
listd = []
for i in xrange(0,sh.nrows):
    if sh.cell_value(rowx=i, colx =1) == b:
        mylist.append(i)
        listd.append(sh.row_values(i))
        print 'the number', b ,'was found in row=', i, 'and column =0'


    if sh.cell_value(rowx=i,colx =1) == c:
        listc.append(i)
        listd.append(sh.row(i))

#mylist[0] #upper limit of my rows
#listc[-1] #lower limit of my rows
listd # this has all of my rows that i want to put in a new excel file
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  If you have a number of csv files that have the same format (same columns . . then it is trivial to read lines and manipulate the line - no need to use xlrd/xlwt.  If you need to confirm that the the columns are the same then you have to use something else in your example you are losing the column headings.

Comment: i have a number of excel files, and in Column B  of each file i have all of my dates as in 04/05/2014. The file contains about 10,000 rows, so i first find out where exactly the first occurance of my sought date is. That gives me the row e.g. say it happens in row 5000. Then i know to grab all the data below that row now, and skip the first 5000 rows. So its an excel file. I make a list of all of these rows. But now i want to take that data, e.g. rows 5000 to 6000, and put them in a new excel file. The problem i am having is i cannot seem to put this data back into another excel file. Helps?

Comment: So the bit of code you showed works except the very end where you don't know how to write your list of rows, `listd`, to your worksheet, `sheet`?

Comment: yes! :) exactly. no idea how i drop this entire list of rows into a sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any `write_row` method in **xlwt** like there is `row_values` in **xlrd**.  There is only [`sheet.write`](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/Worksheet.py#L1029) of the Worksheet object of or `write_rich_text` if need be.

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(listd):
   for col_index, cell_value in enumerate(row):
       sheet.write(row_index, col_index, cell_value)
workbook.save("myData.xls")
```

If there are special styles you can use the optional `style` argument of `write`.